# MySQL NOT IN Query problem

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to search a table where the field `name` does not have a list of strings in it.  I use:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM members  
WHERE name NOT IN ('bob', 'jim', 'leroy');
```

but it still returns matches containing those words.  I have searched high and low for the answer to this.  Can anyone help?

Comment: could you please post a data set containing one of the names you want to filter out?

Answer (score 3):

`name NOT IN ('bob', 'jim', 'leroy')` is equivalent to `name!='bob' and name!='jim' and name!='leroy'`.

Perhaps you want

```
name not like '%bob%' and name not like '%jim%' and name not like '%leroy%'
```

instead?

Comment: yeah but I thought there would be a more efficient way, perhaps not

Comment: @Adam within mysql I think that's as good as it gets.  If you need to improve performance look into an external search engine like http://sphinxsearch.com .

Comment: MySQL has [native Full Text Search functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I suppose I should have mentioned that, but I didn't because it's *way* slower.    Might be good enough for his needs though.

Comment: Slower than a table scan?  I don't think so, but constraining because of only supporting MyISAM.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - No, I meant slower than Sphinx.  To me it seems like the window where it makes sense to use full-text search but not a far-superior option like Sphinx or lucene is pretty small.

Answer (score 1):

This only NOT matches values that are exactly one of the names. You can try `WHERE name NOT LIKE "%bob%" AND NOT LIKE "%jim%" AND NOT LIKE "%leroy%"`